# Removing all IMG tags nested within 'P' class nodes within a master 'DIV'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, dom

I've spent the last few days problem solving how to remove thousands of images from a chat backup that has been exported to HTML, as it takes up unnecessary space for printing.

I have learned that JQuery and/or Javascript would be the best and easiest way to achieve this. I have looked over many, many of the different types of examples, and not a single one works on this HTML document. They work on stand-alone test documents, so I'm at a loss at to where its going wrong.

Note: Too long to read? skip past to after the '' tag, there's a lot of un-necessary formatting going on.

**Original HTML Snippet**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>WeChat</title>

  <style media='screen'>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font: 1em/1.4 Helvetica, Cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
      color: #333;
      font-size: 12px;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .date {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #container {
      width: 500px;
      padding: 0 0 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h3 {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: normal;
      text-align: left;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles {
      background: #F0F0F0;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F0F0F0), to(#F0F0F0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .content {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles2 {
      background: #D2F6CB;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D2F6CB), to(#D2F6CB));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .triangle-isosceles3 {
      background: #D0EDFA;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D0EDFA), to(#D0EDFA));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    hr {
      height: 1px;
      border: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #cccccc;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .imgdic {
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map {
      background: #F0F0F0;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F0F0F0), to(#F0F0F0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .content {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map2 {
      background: #D2F6CB;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D2F6CB), to(#D2F6CB));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    img {
      border-style: none;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none
    }
  </style>
  <style media='print'>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font: 1em/1.4 Helvetica, Cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
      color: #333;
      font-size: 12px;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .date {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #container {
      width: 500px;
      padding: 0 0 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h3 {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: normal;
      text-align: left;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles {
      background: #F0F0F0;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F0F0F0), to(#F0F0F0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .content {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles2 {
      background: #D0EDFA;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D0EDFA), to(#D0EDFA));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .triangle-isosceles3 {
      background: #D2F6CB;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D2F6CB), to(#D2F6CB));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    hr {
      height: 1px;
      border: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #cccccc;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .imgdic {
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      display: none;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map {
      background: #F0F0F0;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F0F0F0), to(#F0F0F0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .content {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map2 {
      background: #D0EDFA;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D0EDFA), to(#D0EDFA));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map3 {
      background: #D2F6CB;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D2F6CB), to(#D2F6CB));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
  </style>

  <head>

    <body>

      <h1 align=center> WeChat</h1> 
      <div id='container'>
        <div class='content'>
                    <p>
            <img width='28' height='28' align='left' src='media/chat_single.png' />
            <h3 style='word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word'> Title Here</h3>
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>-------------------------------------------------------------
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 18:05:00</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles2'><font color='#4D4D4D'> Random Chat Log </font>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
        
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 17:10:14</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles'>
            <a href='media/01-13-2017 17_10_14.jpg' target='_blank'>
              <img src='media/01-13-2017 17_10_14.jpg' style='vertical-align:middle; width:100px;' />
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/3l.png' style='top:-47px;left:-176px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 16:35:02</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles'>
            <a href='media/01-13-2017 16_35_02.jpg' target='_blank'>
              <img src='media/01-13-2017 16_35_02.jpg' style='vertical-align:middle; width:100px;' />
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/3l.png' style='top:-47px;left:-176px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 16:35:00</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles'>
            <a href='media/01-13-2017 16_35_00.jpg' target='_blank'>
              <img src='media/01-13-2017 16_35_00.jpg' style='vertical-align:middle; width:100px;' />
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/3l.png' style='top:-47px;left:-176px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 15:54:36</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles2'><font color='#4D4D4D'> Random Chat Log </font>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/1l.png' style='top:-47px;left:208px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 15:48:18</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles2'><font color='#4D4D4D'> Random Chat Log </font>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/1l.png' style='top:-47px;left:208px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 15:48:12</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles2'><font color='#4D4D4D'> Random Chat Log </font>
          </p>
```

**What I've Tried**

```html
<!-- First Attempt !-->
element.classList.remove("imgdic");
$("class").removeClass("imgdic");

<!-- Second attempt !-->
$("#div img").remove();

<!-- Third attempt !-->
$().ready(function() {
    $("img").load(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

If anyone has any advice or feedback please please let me know!

Comment: `$('.imgdic img').remove()`?

Comment: Are they all inside the `content` div?

Comment: $("p img").remove();

Comment: maybe use powershell or some other tool to remove all lines from all html files using regex...

Comment: @MrB yes they are all under the content div -Tushar- yes your's also worked, thank you!

Comment: I've also noticed some odd behavior, sometimes I have to refresh the page a few times, or make a change in the HTML code before the JavaScript will kick in (i.e the photos are back, then I make a change int he code, they disappear), any known reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
$('a').remove();
$('img').remove();
```

Or you could replace it with a message stating that there was an image there.

Comment: Yes this solves the problem. I had to put it just before the closing div tags near the bottom for it to work though. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm very happy to know that it worked ^^

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!-- Second attempt !-->
$(".content img").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>WeChat</title>

  <style media='screen'>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font: 1em/1.4 Helvetica, Cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
      color: #333;
      font-size: 12px;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .date {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #container {
      width: 500px;
      padding: 0 0 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h3 {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: normal;
      text-align: left;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles {
      background: #F0F0F0;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F0F0F0), to(#F0F0F0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .content {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles2 {
      background: #D2F6CB;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D2F6CB), to(#D2F6CB));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .triangle-isosceles3 {
      background: #D0EDFA;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D0EDFA), to(#D0EDFA));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    hr {
      height: 1px;
      border: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #cccccc;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .imgdic {
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map {
      background: #F0F0F0;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F0F0F0), to(#F0F0F0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .content {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map2 {
      background: #D2F6CB;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D2F6CB), to(#D2F6CB));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    img {
      border-style: none;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none
    }
  </style>
  <style media='print'>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font: 1em/1.4 Helvetica, Cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
      color: #333;
      font-size: 12px;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .date {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #container {
      width: 500px;
      padding: 0 0 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h3 {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: normal;
      text-align: left;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles {
      background: #F0F0F0;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F0F0F0), to(#F0F0F0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .content {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles2 {
      background: #D0EDFA;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D0EDFA), to(#D0EDFA));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .triangle-isosceles3 {
      background: #D2F6CB;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 200px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D2F6CB), to(#D2F6CB));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    hr {
      height: 1px;
      border: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #cccccc;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .imgdic {
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      display: none;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map {
      background: #F0F0F0;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F0F0F0), to(#F0F0F0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      background: linear-gradient(#F0F0F0, #F0F0F0);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .content {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map2 {
      background: #D0EDFA;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D0EDFA), to(#D0EDFA));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      background: linear-gradient(#D0EDFA, #D0EDFA);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
    .triangle-isosceles-map3 {
      background: #D2F6CB;
      word-break: break-all;
      width: 220px;
      left: 170px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1em 0 3em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#D2F6CB), to(#D2F6CB));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      background: linear-gradient(#D2F6CB, #D2F6CB);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      behavior: url(media/pie.htc);
    }
  </style>

  <head>

    <body>

      <h1 align=center> WeChat</h1> 
      <div id='container'>
        <div class='content'>
                    <p>
            <img width='28' height='28' align='left' src='media/chat_single.png' />
            <h3 style='word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word'> Title Here</h3>
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>-------------------------------------------------------------
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 18:05:00</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles2'><font color='#4D4D4D'> Random Chat Log </font>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
        
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 17:10:14</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles'>
            <a href='media/01-13-2017 17_10_14.jpg' target='_blank'>
              <img src='media/01-13-2017 17_10_14.jpg' style='vertical-align:middle; width:100px;' />
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/3l.png' style='top:-47px;left:-176px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 16:35:02</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles'>
            <a href='media/01-13-2017 16_35_02.jpg' target='_blank'>
              <img src='media/01-13-2017 16_35_02.jpg' style='vertical-align:middle; width:100px;' />
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/3l.png' style='top:-47px;left:-176px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 16:35:00</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles'>
            <a href='media/01-13-2017 16_35_00.jpg' target='_blank'>
              <img src='media/01-13-2017 16_35_00.jpg' style='vertical-align:middle; width:100px;' />
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/3l.png' style='top:-47px;left:-176px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 15:54:36</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles2'><font color='#4D4D4D'> Random Chat Log </font>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/1l.png' style='top:-47px;left:208px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 15:48:18</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles2'><font color='#4D4D4D'> Random Chat Log </font>
          </p>
          <p class='imgdic'>
            <img src='media/1l.png' style='top:-47px;left:208px; position:Absolute' />
          </p>
          <p class='date'><font color='#b4b4b4'>01/13/2017 15:48:12</font>
          </p>
          <p class='triangle-isosceles2'><font color='#4D4D4D'> Random Chat Log </font>
          </p>
```